# How to draw a rounded edges for a polygon having its x,y coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, drawing, polygon

I need to draw polygon from X, Y coordinates but with rounded corners I have the points of X, Y

My code is below, however if there is another library, I can use it.

Here my output image:

[image: Test image]

and this is the code

```
def create_mask(dirct,filename,alistofpoint,height,width):
    myimg = np.zeros((height,width), dtype = "uint8")
    po = np.array(alistofpoint, np.int32)
    myimg_mod=cv2.fillPoly(myimg, [po],(255,255))
    cv2.imwrite(dirct+"//"+filename, myimg_mod)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)'s [`ImageDraw`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html) module by first using the coordinates to draw a polygon and then outlining it with a wide line with rounded corners.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def create_mask(directory, filename, alistofpoint, height, width):
    mask = Image.new('L', (width, height), color=0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.polygon(points, fill=255, outline=255)
    draw.line(points, fill=255, width=5, joint='curve')
    mask.save(Path(directory)/filename)
    return mask


pad = 25
points = [(114, 197), (96, 77), (110, 42), (138, 56,), (166, 124), (166, 174), (154, 195)]
width = max(points, key=itemgetter(0))[0] + pad
height = max(points, key=itemgetter(1))[1] + pad

mask = create_mask('\.', 'output_image.png', points, height, width)
mask.show()
```

Here's a 3X enlargement showing the polygon without the outline on the left, and with it drawn on the right. The effect is a little hard to see at such relatively low image resolutions.

[image: screenshot show effect of drawing outline]